# Как узнать id пользователя Linux

Tags: python, linux

Смысл таков, есть скрипт на питоне, и в одной из функций идёт проверка на id пользователя, выглядит примерно так:

```
def check_root():
 if(id == 0):
  print('ROOT!!!')
 else:
  print('NO ROOT!!!')
```

Вопрос в том как получить этот заветный id? Думаю что через os можно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Всё разобрался:

```
def check_root():
 if(os.geteuid() == 0):
  print('ROOT!!!')
 else:
  print('NO ROOT!!!')
```

Comment: так быстро разобрался, видимо хороший специалист!

Comment: хех, документацию прочитал

Comment: @Allespro, надеюсь [man 7 credentials](https://linux.die.net/man/7/credentials) тоже прочли (и выбор `.geteuid()` был осознанным)?

Comment: @avp, то, что выбор был осознанным сказать не могу, остановился на нём так как всё сработало. Если знаете верное решение, подскажите пожалуйста.

Comment: @Allespro, если цель узнать, каковы права процесса именно в данный момент, то `.geteuid()` верное решение. На практике оно так и есть, каким был uid раньше почти никогда не интересно.

Comment: @avp, да именно это и нужно, спасибо.